# Gnuplot parametric surface plot hidden3d / pm3d border problem

Tags: gnuplot

The last couple of hours I've been trying to produce an acceptable-looking plot of a 3D-Object. Now i'm totally stuck at somehow making Gnuplot draw the borders in respect to my 3D-object in a right way. The code I use is this:

```
reset

set term pngcairo enhanced size 800,600
set output "plot.png"

set grid xtics ytics ls 3 lw 1 lc rgb 'gray'

set xzeroaxis
set yzeroaxis

set samples 30,30
set isosamples 30,30

set style line 100 lt 5 lw 0.5 lc black
set palette gray
set cbrange [-1:1]
unset colorbox

set pm3d depthorder hidden3d implicit
set pm3d lighting primary 0.50 specular 0.6

set parametric

set urange [0:2*pi]
set vrange [0:2*pi]
set xrange [-3.1:3.1]
set yrange [-3.1:3.1]
set zrange [-1.1:1.1]

set xyplane at -1
set view 121,115
set xtics offset first 0,0, -0.1
set ytics offset first 0,0, -0.1
set ytics -2,1,2
set xtics -2,1,2

unset border
set border 4095 front lt black linewidth 2.000 dashtype solid

splot (2+cos(u))*cos(v),(2+cos(u))*sin(v),1*sin(v) lc rgb '#666666'

set output
```

If you plot that code it results in an image like this:

[3D-Object Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWLFt.png)

As you can see the layering of Borders/Axes and Graph is somehow messed up. I spent some time playing around with different terminal types, or `set border back / front / behind`, or basically all the other options, but i could not succeed in making Gnuplot draw this the right way, which means, the borders surround my Object.
The only compromise solution i could find, is, if i choose certain different view-points Gnuplot gets it all right. But for the one i want the drawing does not work..
I would be very happy about any suggestions or hints!

Comment: So far as I can tell gnuplot is correctly rendering your border, grid, and object with depth ordering.  It's just that have chosen a viewpoint from which the grid+baseplane is in front. Solution 1 is to rotate the view angle to look from the other side: `set view 57,57; replot`.  Solution 2 is to keep the same view angle but shift the baseplane down far enough that it doesn't block the view: `set xyplane at -3; replot`

Comment: Oh man, thanks a lot! I did not recognize that i was "looking" at the whole thing from below the xy-plane. Solution 1 one is exactly what i wanted :)